Can the order of declarations alter a program?
That is can you by altering the order of declaration still have a valid program, but with a different result. This question is not if you can turn a valid program into an invalid (which you obviously can).
I expect that this could happen on different level of certainty, from the standard mandates different behaviour to fx "just" introducing undefined behaviour.
The question is a bit how confident one should be in rearranging the (overall) source layout. Could one be reasonably sure that things still works the same if it still compiles?
I guess this is a bit of asking about situations where order will/may matter, since it's now obvious that such situations exist (and if there's trivial countermeasures).

Within a single translation unit, global constructors are appearance-ordered. Is that what you mean?

Accidentally moving function overloads behind their first (intended) use also prevents them from being invoked and can lead to a different function being invoked. Example here: https://godbolt.org/z/YxcbqGG6T

@Homer512 Yes, those are situation where programs could change. For the second I guess that a compiler could warn about (or?). The first is a bit trickier, to guard agains perhaps, but it would perhaps require them to rely on things they shoudn't (some cases leading to UB)

Declarations can involve evaluating expressions (constructors obviously but really an initializer can include an arbitrary expression). Expressions can have side effects. So clearly altering the order of declarations may change the meaning of a program. Seems obvious so maybe you are asking about something more subtle.

I wouldn't expect a compiler to give a warning for Homer's second example.   Too many similar examples (e.g. if foo(double) is not visible at all when compiling the source file containing main(), and main() is not visible when compiling a separate compilation unit that contains foo(double)) where a compiler cannot feasibly detect the concern and give a warning about it.    The usual approach would be to verify that a program passes all mandatory test cases both before and after "altering" the source - problem is getting a set of test cases that is complete enough to catch the concern.

@Peter There's a difference when foo(double) doesn't appear at all and foo(double) appears after a part where earlier mention of foo(double) would make a difference. The later situation is one that I think a compiler could detect (and I see no reasonable reason why one would like to do that either).

@skyking   I understand what the difference is.   The rules of the language allow (even encourage) a single-pass compiler (i.e. the compiler does not need to revisit all previous code in a source file whenever it encounters a new declaration), as that makes compilation faster.   To meet your expectation, the compiler would need to do multiple passes over each file (each time it encounters a declaration, reexamine [the representation of] all previous code in the source file) which would hurt compilation speed badly.,  For something that few developers actually need in practice.

@Peter That doesn't mean it's impossible for a compiler to do so, well maybe that's perhaps more of a task for a lint tool. What I mean is that such a construct is both quite detectable and also quite questionable as far as I can see. But OTOH the situation with global constructors being that order sensitive is questionabe to some extend and could be detected (even if that means having to analyse the codebase as a whole)

@skyking I didn't say it's impossible for a compiler to do.   I said it's not likely to be a priority for compiler developers.  It's something that most developers (users of the compiler) will rarely use (most developers don't regularly reorder declarations in headers or source files at all, and usually understand the implications if they do), it will slow down compilation times (which most developers will resist) and there is cost/effort involved to implement such things in a compiler.

The "static initialization order fiasco" is a well-known informal term originating from Marshall Cline's C++ FAQ: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order. This all boils down to C++ allowing code to get executed during initialization. There's no trivial fix - C++ has created an obfuscated storage duration system to handle all manner of initialization scenarios. Read C++20 6.7.5 and weep.

Yes, there are many ways in which the order can matter:

Name lookup can result in different entities depending on whether the declaration containing the point of the lookup is before or after another declaration. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/cY7jM9s3d
Overload resolution and partial specialization matching considers only previously-declared entities and it is (usually) perfectly valid to declare better candidates later. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/fY367a85q
Whether or not a function is previously-defined (rather than just declared) can affect whether or not expressions are constant expressions, which in turn can affect other things like overload resolution. Similarly, whether or not a const integral or enumeration variable has a previous initialization sometimes affects whether or not it can be used in a constant expression.
The order of initialization of static storage duration objects depends (sometimes) on the order in which their definitions appear. Changing the order can change the results of the initializations if they depend on one-another.
etc.

There is even one infamous mechanism that can be used to introduce actual compile-time state, via so-called friend-injection.
And even worse, changing the order of declarations can even affect parsing. During parsing of C++ there are many situations in which it is necessary to check whether a name refers to a type or template and the result will affect how following tokens are interpreted. It is possible that the following code parses differently depending on whether or not a type or template declaration for a given name is present before that point.

In my understanding points 1, 3 and 4 may affect how the compiler generates the code (e.g. call a yet unknown function instead of inline the known code), but as long as there are no contradicting declarations/definitions, the code should still work and and execute the same functionality. Or am I wrong? Ambiguous overloads (from point 2) should usually produce warnings or errors so it is difficult to get a surprise modification. For template specializations I am not so sure about warnings/errors due to ambiguous specializations. So normally you should not get unnoticed behavior changes.

@Thibe No, all of them can cause different behavior without any warning. Give me a moment and I'll write up some examples.

@Thibe I've added an example for 1 and 2. I'll do the rest when I get time to do so.

Thanks, now I see. Most problems can be easily be prevented with a good code structure. For example put all declarations for an overloaded function into the same separate header, so you have less chance to mix up the order so badly (the calling code sees all overloads before it picks one), but nothing can stop you to implement dangerous dependency orders.

There's also such a simple thing as changing the order of members of a class/struct changing the amount of padding and thus the size of the object, which can have effects on memory and cache use/effectiveness.
